# How do I set what plot() labels the x-axis with?

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot() that I'm trying to make, but I do not want the x-values to be used as the axis labels...I want a different character vector that I want to use as labels, in the standard way: Use as many as will fit, drop the others, etc. What should I pass to plot() to make this happen?

For example, consider

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=10:15,x.names=c('a','b','c','d','e'))
```

In barplot, I would pass `barplot(height=d$y,names.arg=d$x.names)`, but in this case the actual x-values are important. So I would like an analog such as `plot(x=d$x,y=d$y,type='l',names.arg=d$x.names)`, but that does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Replace X-axis with own values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/r-replace-x-axis-with-own-values)

Answer (score 51):

I think you want to first suppress the labels on the x axis with the xaxt="n" option:

```
plot(flow~factor(month),xlab="Month",ylab="Total Flow per Month",ylim=c(0,55000), xaxt="n")
```

then use the axis command to add in your own labels. This example assumes the labels are in an object called month.name

```
axis(1, at=1:12, labels=month.name)
```

I had to look up how to do this and [I stole the example from here](http://www.nabble.com/replacing-default-axis-labels-on-a-plot-td23538822.html).

Comment: For those that don't know: month.name is a built-in constant containing "January", "February", ..., "December".  Similarly month.abb gives "Jan", ..., "Dec".

Comment: thank you! this worked for me; should be marked as answered, no?

Comment: maybe it didn't work for the original asker. *shrug* who knows?

Comment: @JD Long: Still worked almost seven years later, thanks a lot!

Comment: glad that the language is not changing too quickly!