# Replace X-axis with own values

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have a question regarding the command plot().

Is there a way to fully eliminate the x-axis and replace it with own values? I know that I can get rid of the axis by doing

```
plot(x,y, xaxt = 'n')
```

and then add an axis with

```
axis(side = 1 etc.)
```

However, when I add the axis, obviously it still refers to the data plotted as 'x'. 
I would only like to plot the 'y'-values and add the x-axis my own in the sense of just "drawing" the x-axis with own values specified. Is there any way to do that?

The background of this question is that my two data frames differ in their length and therefore I cannot plot them.

Comment: Do you want to plot vectors with different lengths or just want to set the x label by yourself? Could you provide an example or give more information about the datset?

Comment: You might also want to see how to combine two data frames together.  You might be able to make more plots from your data and probably probably make the data more informative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: How do I set what plot() labels the x-axis with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395577/r-how-do-i-set-what-plot-labels-the-x-axis-with)

Comment: possible duplicate of [R, change the spacing of tick marks on the axis of a plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/r-change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as x axis ticks in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you mean, but you can do this:

```
plot(1:10, xaxt = "n", xlab='Some Letters')
axis(1, at=1:10, labels=letters[1:10])
```

which then gives you the graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tim! Not exactly what I was looking for but it helped my do what I wanted =)

Comment: x and y are the same length in this case. how do you draw n labels when the length of the other axis is m?

Comment: just for reference: the `xaxt="n"` option in the `plot` command suppresses the labeling of the x-axis. If this option is not included, `axis` will be a NOOP.

Comment: This works, but how do I rotate it so it is vertical? las=2 doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the solution. `xaxt = "n"` option worked for ts-class time series. But, in the case of multiple time series (mts-class) it did not work.

Comment: if anyone is looking for the same problem in ggplot2 look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529252/changing-x-axis-tick-labels-in-r-using-ggplot2).

Answer (score 22):

You could set `labels = FALSE` inside `axis(...)` and then print the labels in a separate command using `text(...)`. This option would allow you to rotate the text in case you need it.

```
lablist<-as.vector(c(1:10))
axis(1, at=seq(1, 10, by=1), labels = FALSE)
text(seq(1, 10, by=1), par("usr")[3] - 0.2, labels = lablist, srt = 45, pos = 1, xpd = TRUE)
```

Detailed explanation [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-change-the-angle-of-the-value-labels-on-my-axes/)

[image: Image with rotated labels]