# How to force axis values to scientific notation in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 df <- data.frame(y=seq(1, 1e5, length.out=100), x=sample(100))
 p  <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
 p
```

Which produce this image:

[image]

As mentioned in the image above how can I change the
y-axis value to scientific notation?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529252/changing-x-axis-values-tick-labels-in-r-using-ggplot2

Comment: Load the `scales` package and then add `scale_y_continuous(labels = scientific)` to your plot.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can pass a `format` function with scientific notation turned on to *scale_y_continuous labels* parameter:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: or `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::scientific)`