# How to force y axis to return values in scientific notation in R boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

How can I force the y axis to display the numbers in scientific notation with 'e'. For example, instead of 0.01, it should show "e-02". Here is my code below.

```
boxplot(large1k$Damping_error,small1k$Damping_error,large4k$Damping_error,small4k$Damping_error,large8k$Damping_error,small8k$Damping_error,large16k$Damping_error,small16k$Damping_error,large32k$Damping_error,small32k$Damping_error,col=c("blue","red","blue","red","blue","red","blue","red","blue","red"),names=c("1k","1k","4k","4k","8k","8k","16k","16k","32k","32k"),las.y=1,xlab="Sample  size",ylab="Damping error",log="y",cex.axis=1.2,cex.lab=1.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323247/how-to-force-axis-values-to-scientific-notation-in-ggplot

Comment: `options(scipen = 1)`

Comment: @KotaMori Yes, in ggplot it is possible, but what about in boxplot function. I find it easier to use boxplot than ggplot

Comment: @RonakShah I have tried it actually but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably need to do something like this.

```r
labels_at <- seq(0, 25, 5)
labels <- scales::label_scientific(digits=2)(labels_at)
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", yaxt="n")
axis(side=2, at=labels_at, labels=labels)
```

[image]