# ggplot smart plotting date and time

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have an experiment which lasts from `2018/06/28 08:00:00` to `2018/06/29 07:00:00` (24 hours). Since I had more observations per hour at different minutes, but I needed to plot the hourly mean I cutted out minutes and seconds.

Now my time data is in following form: `2018/06/28 08, 2018/06/28 09,  2018/06/28 10 ... 2018/06/29 07`.

If I plot the values now they are in the right order, but the `x axis` doesn't look good, because the `x label` is too long. If I change the date format with the hour only, `ggplot` is mixing my data because it orders the hours `00, 01, 02...` But my experiment starts on 08 and ends at 07.

How to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. You're telling us you need to change a plot, but we can't see anything

Comment: If the answer gives you the solution, you can validate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, there is a clear lack of information. But, I hope you use `ggplot` and that your problem is only a problem of displaying nice x args ticks like in : [Changing x axis tick labels in R using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529252/changing-x-axis-tick-labels-in-r-using-ggplot2).

So I made a simple exemple :

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(paste("xargsfartoolonghowIwilldeal", 1:n)),
                 y = rnorm(n))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

You can just kill all x ticks :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

You can change x ticks arguments :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste("T", 1:n)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

You can modify the orientation/aspect of the ticks :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5, angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to do! With the custom x axis I can find a shorter text and still the right order for my values. Thanks