# Change Axis Label - R scatterplot

Tags: r, r-car

I am using the CAR library scatterplot function trying to do something similar to [R: Replace X-axis with own values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/r-replace-x-axis-with-own-values).  However the result is badly formatted.  Does anyone know how to replace the x axis values when using scatterplot?  My code is below

```
library(car)
dat = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
scatterplot(y~x, data=dat, xlab="X axis", ylab="Y Axis", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(1,10,2), labels=letters[1:5])
```

With the resulting image

[image: Bad Scatter Plot]

Comment: `xlim=c(lower:upper)` ?

Comment: WHAT does "result is badly formatted" actually mean?

Comment: @hd - adding that to axes(..) didn't seem to change anything.  You can use pos=1.2 to get rid of the vertical space but I haven't found anything to change to horizontal alignment or spacing

Comment: @BondedDust - I thought it would be fairly obvious from the picture but the lettered labeling along the x axis does not align with the tick marks in both scale and spacing.  If you look at the link you can contrast with a graph I consider to be correctly formatted.

Comment: I thought you were referring to how the letters were produced. You actually were bothered by the registration of the labels and tick marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the `car:::scatterplot` help page, as it seems is my calling in life, ....

```
reset.par   if TRUE then plotting parameters are reset to their previous values when scatterplot 
            exits; if FALSE then the mar and mfcol parameters are altered for the current 
            plotting device. Set to FALSE if you want to add graphical elements (such as lines) 
            to the plot.
```

Set it to FALSE and try again.

```
png(); scatterplot(y~x, data=dat, xlab="X axis", ylab="Y Axis", xaxt="n", reset.par=FALSE)
 axis(1, at=seq(1,10,2), labels=letters\[1:5\])
dev.off()
```

[image]