# Is it possible to plot multiple ecdf and cdf in one plot using cdf?

Tags: r, cdf, ecdf

I'm making a cdf for my dataset x,y, and z. How do I put them in one plot?

Im using fitdist to obtain the ecdf and cdf for x,y, and z.

```
  ## Say if we have 
  x=runif(30)
  y=runif(30) 
  z=runif(30)

  ## To fit the distribution I used fitdist 
   a=fitdist(x, "norm")
   b=fitdist(y, "norm")
   c=fitdist(z, "norm")

   par(mfcol=c(1,3))
   cdfcomp(a, xlab="yield loss", ylab="probability", main="1st Stage",      datacol="black", fitcol="green")
   cdfcomp(b, xlab="yield loss", ylab="probability", main="2nd Stage",datacol="gray", fitcol="blue")
   cdfcomp(c, xlab="yield loss", ylab="probability",main="3rd Stage",datacol="navy", fitcol="red")
```

These codes give a three separate plots. Is there a way to put them in the same plot?

I tried doing

```
    cdfcomp(list(a,b, c), horizontals = FALSE)
```

but it gives the following message

```
   "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
    All compared fits must have been obtained with the same dataset."
```

What do I do?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289046/r-ecdf-over-histogram) help?

Comment: Please specify packages you are using ...

Comment: Im using fitdist()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, use `add = TRUE`:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
x=runif(30)
y=runif(30) 
z=runif(30)
a=fitdist(x, "norm")
b=fitdist(y, "norm")
c=fitdist(z, "norm")
cdfcomp(a, xlab="yield loss", ylab="probability", datacol="black", fitcol="green")
cdfcomp(b, datacol="gray", fitcol="blue", add = TRUE)
cdfcomp(c, datacol="navy", fitcol="red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]