# Changing y label plyr R studio

Tags: r

pretty new to R studio and R in general, I have a 3d scattered plot using the library scatterplot3d

The snip of code I have as follows:

```
s3d <- scatterplot3d(averageTime$Score, averageTime$Status, averageTime$Time, pch=16,  highlight.3d=TRUE, type="h", main="3D Scatterplot", ylab="status", xlab= "Score", zlab="Time")
```

Right now the y axis comes out as 0-5 but I want to fill in custom text to replace it so as opposed to 0 I want the text "NA", 1 I would want "Covered"ect

Ive already tried applying the previous question seen here but to no avail: [R: Replace X-axis with own values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/r-replace-x-axis-with-own-values)

please let me know if there is an easier application.  Thank you

[image]

Comment: yes consolidated the data from plyr I should change the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

```
    scatterplot3d(1:10, 1:10, 1:10,  y.ticklabs=c("NA", "Covered", "Blah", "blub", "hmpf", "etc."))
```