# plotting only selected dates on x axis in R

Tags: r, date, plot

I am trying to plot dates vertically in year-month format on X axis between 1850 and 2016. When I use the following code, all dates are printed on screen on top of each other and nothing is legible. I would like to tell R to print selected dates on my plot, ideally with 10 year intervals (eg. print January 1850, January 1860 etc). How do I do this?

```
plot(DF$Date, DF$Value, pch = 16, cex = 1, col = "red", main = "Title", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Value", las=2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Replace X-axis with own values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/r-replace-x-axis-with-own-values)

Comment: The thread you mention does not tell me how to include selected dates.