# How to show to date instead of periods at x-axis in time series forecast plot?

Tags: r, forecasting, holtwinters

I have a simple time series dataset: df1, in format like:

```
    Item | Date     | Var
      1  | 20000101 | 12
      2  | 20000102 | 13
      3  | 20000103 | 16
      4  | 20000104 | 18
      5  | 20000105 | 29
      6  | 20000106 | 36
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      365| 20001231 | 78
```

My code is:

```
    varts <- ts(df1$var, frequency=7)
    comp <- decompose(varts)
    plot(comp)
    fcmodel <- HoltWinters(varts)
    plot(forecast(fcmodel, h=30, level=c(80,95)))
```

I got a simple forecast plot but the x-axis ranges from 0 to 50 instead of the date.
I would like to present the plot with real date at x-axis, which is meaningful to explain my data.
But I am lost in tons of explanation on the web, failed with every method I found.
I really appreciate if anyone could help with this question.

Comment: Please share output of `dput(df1)` or `head(dput(df1),60)` in the question description so that someone can easily reproduce the data.frame at your end and work out a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I did not figure out how this works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

# generate dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(seq(1, 365, 1), seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2000-12-30'), 1), round(100*runif(365), 0))
names(df1) <- c('item','date','var')

varts <- ts(df1$var, frequency=7)
comp <- decompose(varts)
plot(comp)
fcmodel <- HoltWinters(varts)

plot(forecast(fcmodel, h=30, level=c(80,95)), xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=seq(0, 80,10) , las=2, labels=seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2000-12-31')+weeks(30), length.out=9) )
```

The last two lines essentially copy the approach from here [Replace X-axis with own values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/replace-x-axis-with-own-values).

You can edit the labels and their locations by editing the 'at=' and 'lables=' -parameters.

[image: Here is what the output looks like]

Comment: When you get fed up with base R plotting, you might also want to take a look at this:  https://www.r-bloggers.com/holt-winters-forecast-using-ggplot2/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Otto! I've been working with the article posted on r-bloggers, but did not work out by now.

Comment: Yeah I gave the r-bloggers function a try too. Seems that it does not work with the current version of ggplot2. Pity.