# Axis function in R not giving me required results

Tags: r, plot, axis

**Problem** - I am trying to plot a graph but wish to change the x axis and y axis values. With the help of stackoverflow, I understood how to use axis() to customize values but I am unable to get the required output. Whenever I run this below code, only one label on the x axis is being displayed. Here, x contains some numbers. Here is a screenshot [image]

**Tries** - I tried to give a character vector to the label field in the axis function, I tried changing Months to a data frame, nothing seems to help.

**Goal** - To display all the months of the year on x-axis and its corresponding data (Assuming that first element of vector x belongs to 1st month of the year and so on)

```
data <- data.frame( x= c(0,42,100,560,800, 900, 1000, 1200, 4800,5000, 5600, 6700, 8000, 12000) , 10, replace= TRUE)

plot(x, xaxt="n", type = "l")
xtick <- seq(1,12, by = 1)
Months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec")
axis(side=1, at=xtick, labels = Months)
```

**If someone could help me and guide where I am going wrong, it would be great**

Comment: `plot(data, xaxt="n", type = "l")` gives an error, maybe try with `data$x`?

Comment: also look at `str(data)`, are you sure the example code is correct?

Comment: Riccardo Lavelli - I am sorry, i have edited the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
data <- data.frame( x= c(0,42,100,560,800, 900, 1000, 1200, 4800,5000, 5600, 6700, 8000, 12000))

plot(y =data$x, x = 1:length(data$x), type = "l", xaxt = "n")

Months <- as.vector(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec", "Jan", "Feb"))
axis(1, at=1:length(data$x), labels= Months)
```

The answer can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/replace-x-axis-with-own-values)

Comment: Carles Sans Fuentes Thank you so much. This indeed works.