# Change tick mark labels to specific strings in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have `plotly` graphics where I'd like to change axis tick mark labels to specific strings. Consider the following example:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
```

[image]

Say I want to supress all numeric xaxis tick mark labels and instead only plot the string "min" at `x = 4.5` and "max" at `x = 8`.

How can I achieve this in `plotly`?

---

**Sidenote**: I know this is possible for base R plots, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/replace-x-axis-with-own-values) and in `ggplot2` by setting `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4.5, 8), labels= c("4.5" = "min", "8" = "max"))`.

Is there also a way to achieve this in `plotly`?
..Unfortunately the `plotly` [docs](https://plot.ly/r/axes/) don't seem to offer a solution..

Comment: I'm not sure about plotly, but you can convert a ggplot using the `ggplotly` function to get a similar result: `p2 = ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(colour=hcl(255,100,65)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=5:8, labels=LETTERS[5:8]);
ggplotly(p2)`. The theme can be tweaked a bit more to get closer to the p

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with the details of plotly, but perhaps the [help for `ticktext`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-ticktext) could be useful.

Comment: In case it helps, this post goes through the workings of how `ggplotly` pipes from `ggplot2` to `plotly`. It shows how `plotly_json(p2)` would show what is being sent to `plotly` so that you might recreate it more directly inside your `plot_ly` function.  https://moderndata.plot.ly/learning-from-and-improving-upon-ggplotly-conversions/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @eipi10 and @Jon Spring I could figure it out:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickvals = c(4.5, 8), ticktext = c("min", "max")))
```

This is exactly what I was searching for and produces:

[image]