# Modifying the X-Axis in R

Tags: r

[image]

I have plotted a signal sampled at 20Hz and length of signal is 3940 (197 seconds)
I want to modify the x-axis such that instead of showing limits from 0-3940 it shows 0-197s

Comment: please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can try out your code or make improvements. Also you could just recalculate the Data before plotting it. If 3940 = 197 just calculate it and then Plot it.

Comment: I have a signal of 197second which is sampled at 20Hz sampling rate so it has 3940 value, when I plot the time is in (Second*20), I just want to divide the X-Axis values by 20 so I get the same plot but with new x-axis i.e. in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to `plot` your data without x-axis then you can add a custom one.
refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5182416/5224236)
If your data is named `df` you can use:

```
plot(1:nrow(df), xaxt = "n", xlab='Axis Title')
axis(1, at=1:10, labels=seq(0, 197, by=nrow(df)/198)
```

If instead you have a vector you should use:

```
plot(1:length(df), xaxt = "n", xlab='Axis Title')
axis(1, at=1:10, labels=seq(0, 197, by=length(df)/198)
```

Comment: I tried changing the axis i.e. plot(1:10, xaxt = "n", xlab='Some Letters')
axis(1, at=1:10, labels=letters[1:10])

Comment: see edits: you have to use `nrow(df)` if you have a `data.frame` or `length(vec)` if you have a vector. It would be easier to help you if you share your current code by editing your question.