# renaming factor name in factanal

Tags: r

```
data_factanal <- factanal(data2[, -1],
                         factors = 2,
                         rotation = 'varimax',
                         scores = 'regression')

plot(data_factanal$scores)
```

result:
[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0kGe.jpg)

is there any way to change name 'Factor1' and 'Factor2' in plot?

what i tried: find library and googling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace X-axis with own values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182238/replace-x-axis-with-own-values) - just do `plot(data_factanal$scores, xlab = "whatever", ylab = "something else")`. See the help for the [`plot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/plot.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename `data_factanal$scores`:

```
  colnames(data_factanal$scores) <- c("new_name_1", "new_name_2")
  plot(data_factanal$scores)
```

[image]